# How to mock Elasticsearch .Net client?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, elasticsearch, mocking, nest

I am using Elasticsearch .Net Client 6.x, and I have some code like:

```
if(this.elasticClient.IndexExists("indexName").Exists){
    // do something
}

this.elasticClient.CreateIndex(
    newIndex,
    x => x.Settings(s => s.NumberOfShards(1)).Mappings(ms => ms.Map<T>(m => m.AutoMap())));

var searchResponse = client.Search<dynamic>(
    s => s.AllTypes()
        .Index(
            new[] { "indexName1", "indexName"}).IgnoreUnavailable().Size(size).From(from).Query(
            q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(m => m.SimpleQueryString(c => c.Query(query).Lenient().AnalyzeWildcard())))));
```

Now in my unit test, I'd like to test the exact `descriptor` passed to each method, how can I do this?

```
var existsResponse = new Mock<ExistsResponse>();
existsResponse.Setup(x => x.Exists).Returns(false);  // Oops: can't do this since Exists is not virtual, abstract
this.elasticClient.Setup(x => x.IndexExists("indexName", null)).Returns(existsResponse.Object);

this.elasticClient.Verify(
    x => x.CreateIndex("IndexName", It.Is<Func<CreateIndexDescriptor, ICreateIndexRequest>>(x => /*what goes here??*/)),
    Times.Once);

this.elasticClient.Verify(
    x => x.Search<dynamic>(It.Is<Func<SearchDescriptor<dynamic>>>(x => /*what goes here??*/)),
    Times.Once);
```

Should I just simply wrap the elasticClient in a class and implement every method I used, and pass it as dependency injection?